# How to access JS class methods when identifying object via DOM selector

Tags: javascript, class

Let's say I want to create a JavaScript class, something like the below. Let's also say that at a previous point in time, I have created a few instances of that class.

```
class Fruit {
    doSomething(input){
        // something to do in here;
    }
}

let apple = new Fruit();
let banana = new Fruit();
let orange = new Fruit();
```

Now, let's say I want to be able to access that `doSomething()` method. In my scenario, I want to access the method for the object that corresponds to the value in an HTML selector.

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
     <option value="apple">apple</option>
     <option value="banana">banana</option>
     <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
```

```
let selectedFruit = document.getElementById("fruit");
selectedFruit.doSomething();
```

However, when I try something like this, the specific error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: selectedFruit.doSomething is not a function
```

So while `doSomething()` is a method on the `Fruit` class, and while I've created a few objects that are instances of the `Fruit` class, whenever I try to dynamically identify which object to perform the `doSomething()` method on, I get that error.

How can I solve this?

In my use case, the user could add new fruit to their dropdown at any point, so I do need to be able to dynamically identify which object to perform the `doSomething()` based on what is currently selected.

Also, apologies if I've used incorrect terminology / confusing phrasing at any point, I'm still very much a learner so I may have used the wrong word(ing) somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in an object and you can use bracket notation to reference it.

```js
class Fruit {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  doSomething(input) {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const basket = {
  apple: new Fruit('a'),
  banana: new Fruit('b'),
  orange: new Fruit('o')
};

document.querySelector("#fruit").addEventListener("change", function () {
  basket[this.value].doSomething();
});
```

```html
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
```